# How can I find flash drives with low power consumption?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, power, iphone, ios

(First off, I wasn't sure if my question is more suitable for this site or Ask Different. But I ask and if the latter, please tell me)

I have an iPhone 11 with iOS 13 and want to use a flash drive for transferring files from/to it. I've got the official apple camera kit and the 2 flash drives I used work fine with the only **problem of also needing the external power**. But for example if I connect mouse/keyboard, power connection is not needed.

So my question is: Do we have low-power flash drives for this kind of usage? If so, is it mentioned in the specifications that I can recognize?

Comment: What are the specifications of iPhone itself? How much power can it supply, and why is it so low compared to regular USB ports? (I've been able to run even a spinning 2.5" HDD from a Nexus phone, so "not enough for a flash drive" really seems unusual for any OTG-capable device.)

Comment: @grawity I know. Coming from an Android phone, I am confused. I Searched but couldn't find any specifications on the adapter of how much power it provides to the USB 3 port...

Comment: In general USB flash drives are low power.  You can test this out yourself with an in-line USB voltage & current meter.  E.G. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000180005457.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.cf062040oaF08y&algo_pvid=de6446ee-f937-4f2e-855f-0aa99db2ae1e&algo_expid=de6446ee-f937-4f2e-855f-0aa99db2ae1e-4&btsid=2574fddc-878a-4820-9b49-5d940b10c549&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5,searchweb201603_53